# Jersey Maven with Eclipse Oxygen 3A "Could not resolve archetype org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes:jersey-quickstart-webapp:2.30.1"

Tags: eclipse, maven, jersey-2.0, maven-archetype

After reading lots of questions about same issue here on SO, I was unable to resolve it.

I am trying to do a quick basic restfull web app in eclipse (Oxygen 3A) using Jersey framework.  However, I am unable to add the archetype for some reason and get this error
**"Could not resolve archetype org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes:jersey-quickstart-webapp:2.30.1"**.

I went to Window > Properties > Maven > Archetypes and added remote archetype catalog like on image below
[image]

As you can see, it found about 37K archetypes, so next I create new maven project and filter for "jersey" and as you can see below, I select "jersey-quickstart-webapp":
[image]

Click Next and enter the groupId, artifact id, version, package for my project
[image]

Click Finish and I get this error
[image]

I tried also few older versions of this archetype but keep getting same error.  Here is more detail about the error:

[image]

Comment: Is this the current release of Eclipse?

Comment: No, it is Eclipse Oxygen 3A and I am following this tutorial and doing it all as in the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DWPN45AJA3k (see around 5 min into the video)